# How can I receive email alerts on a keyword?

Tags: support, tags, email-notification, alerts

I would like to receive an email alert on new questions containing a specific keyword. I have seen that it is possible to receive such alerts for a specific tag.

Unfortunately, this keyword is not yet associated to a tag. Is there a solution to this issue, or should I wait until I got 1500 reputation to create a tag for it?

Comment: What's the keyword? It quite possibly should not be a tag. (In any event, if it doesn't already exist, why would new questions use it?)

Comment: You could set up a Google Alert for it I guess.

Comment: You can also suggest that the tag be created.

Comment: if you use the wrong keyword you will fill your email in a bunch of seconds

Comment: @Bart Thanks for the Google Alert tip.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it is a keyword worth following, it needs a tag. That's what tags are for, to discover new questions for a given subject.

Because tags already support following (in various different ways, including RSS, email and websocket-powered dedicated pages), no other 'follow a keyword' functionality is available.

If you find that the specific keyword you want to follow is used by a decent number of questions, you can request that a tag is created for it. Post a tag request here on Meta and we can help create it for you.

Comment: Just... make sure it's a tag that's valid, and not a meta tag like "design" or "problem", of course. =)

Comment: @J.Steen: When someone posts here on Meta to ask for a tag like that, I'm sure the community will educate the OP of what makes a proper tag. :-P

Comment: Thoroughly. I've seen it happen.