# Ability to get notifications for keywords (not tags)

Tags: feature-request, tags, email-notification, alerts

I'm not sure how feasible this would be, but it could be nice in many cases to be able to subscribe for alerts on questions having a specific keywords.  I saw a similar questions [asked before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171686/how-can-i-receive-email-alerts-on-a-keyword), but that person's reasoning was because the word was not yet a tag.

My reason for asking for this is because even if there is a tag for the word I want to subscribe to, many people don't fill out the Tags for their question, even though the question clearly related to that word. Even though I'm registered for notifications for a certain tag, I still find myself doing a search every few days for that exact same word and I always find questions that are very relevant but simply weren't tagged.

In an ideal world, people would always tag with everything, or reviewers would review every question in detail and add all relevant tags. But practically, this doesn't happen.

I wanted to get your thoughts on whether or not this should be supported